# Sort list of objects in python using custom sort logic function with cmp_to_key

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a list of objects in python, where a single object has 2 attributes ie. `a` and `b`, `a` can be either `None` or `dict` and b is an `int` or `None`, I want the resultant list to be sorted like:

1. It should have first all objects with `a equal to None`.
2. Then it should have all objects with `a not equal to None`.
3. In 1, 2 if those objects have `b` (`b is int`) then sort them with b.

Example result:

```
[
    Obj(a=None, b=2), 
    Obj(a=None, b=5), 
    Obj(a=None, b=None), 
    Obj(a=dict, b=1), 
    Obj(a=dict, b=4), 
    Obj(a=dict, b=None)
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it using `sorted()`, and a similar approach would work with the `sort()` method of the `list` datatype:

```
        class Obj:
            def __init__(self, a, b):
                self.a = a
                self.b = b
        
        input = [
            Obj(a=dict(), b=1), 
            Obj(a=dict(), b=None),
            Obj(a=None, b=5), 
            Obj(a=None, b=None), 
            Obj(a=dict(), b=4), 
            Obj(a=None, b=2),
        ]
        output = sorted(input, key=lambda x: (x.a is not None, x.b is None, x.b))
        [print(f"Obj(a={'dict' if x.a is not None else 'None'}, b={x.b})") for x in output]
```

Output:

```
Obj(a=None, b=2)
Obj(a=None, b=5)
Obj(a=None, b=None)
Obj(a=dict, b=1)
Obj(a=dict, b=4)
Obj(a=dict, b=None)
```

Comment: @Shikhar Tyagi Did this answer your question? Do you need any additional help?

Comment: yes this did help, thanks :)